# How do you stringize/serialize Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, serialization, lambda, proc-object

I want to be able to write a lambda/Proc in my Ruby code, serialize it so that I can write it to disk, and then execute the lambda later.  Sort of like...

```
x = 40
f = lambda { |y| x + y }
save_for_later(f)
```

Later, in a separate run of the Ruby interpreter, I want to be able to say...

```
f = load_from_before
z = f.call(2)
z.should == 42
```

Marshal.dump does not work for Procs.  I know Perl has [Data::Dump::Streamer](http://search.cpan.org/~yves/Data-Dump-Streamer-2.08-40/lib/Data/Dump/Streamer.pm), and in Lisp this is trivial.  But is there a way to do it in Ruby?  In other words, what would be the implementation of `save_for_later`?

**Edit**: [My answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199603/how-do-you-stringize-serialize-ruby-code/199803#199803) is nice, but it does not close over free variables (like `x`) and serialize them along with the lambda.  So in my example ...

```
x = 40
s = save_for_later { |y| x + y }
# => "lambda { |y|\n  (x + y)\n}"
```

... the string output does not include a definition for `x`.  Is there a solution that takes this into account, perhaps by serializing the symbol table?  Can you access that in Ruby?

**Edit 2**: I updated my answer to incorporate serializing local variables.  This seems acceptable.

Comment: Why am I getting -1'd on this question? I didn't answer or comment here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Use Ruby2Ruby**

```
def save_for_later(&block)
  return nil unless block_given?

  c = Class.new
  c.class_eval do
    define_method :serializable, &block
  end
  s = Ruby2Ruby.translate(c, :serializable)
  s.sub(/^def \S+\(([^\)]*)\)/, 'lambda { |\1|').sub(/end$/, '}')
end

x = 40
s = save_for_later { |y| x + y }
# => "lambda { |y|\n  (x + y)\n}"
g = eval(s)
# => #<Proc:0x4037bb2c@(eval):1>
g.call(2) 
# => 42
```

This is great, but it does not close over free variables (like `x`) and serialize them along with the lambda.

To [serialize variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503583/how-do-you-access-the-symbol-table-in-ruby) also, you can iterate over `local_variables` and serialize them as well.  The problem, though, is that `local_variables` from within `save_for_later` accesses only `c` and `s` in the code above -- i.e. variables local to the serialization code, not the caller.  So unfortunately, we must push the grabbing of local variables and their values to the caller.

Maybe this is a good thing, though, because in general, finding all free variables in a piece of Ruby code is [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable).  Plus, ideally we would also save `global_variables` and any loaded classes and their overridden methods.  This seems impractical.

Using this simple approach, you get the following:

```
def save_for_later(local_vars, &block)
  return nil unless block_given?

  c = Class.new
  c.class_eval do
    define_method :serializable, &block
  end
  s = Ruby2Ruby.translate(c, :serializable)
  locals = local_vars.map { |var,val| "#{var} = #{val.inspect}; " }.join
  s.sub(/^def \S+\(([^\)]*)\)/, 'lambda { |\1| ' + locals).sub(/end$/, '}')
end

x = 40
s = save_for_later(local_variables.map{ |v| [v,eval(v)] }) { |y| x + y }
# => "lambda { |y| _ = 40; x = 40;\n  (x + y)\n}"

# In a separate run of Ruby, where x is not defined...
g = eval("lambda { |y| _ = 40; x = 40;\n  (x + y)\n}")
# => #<Proc:0xb7cfe9c0@(eval):1>
g.call(2)
# => 42

# Changing x does not affect it.
x = 7
g.call(3)
# => 43
```

Comment: My version of Ruby2Ruby (1.2.4) doesn't seem to have a translate method. Is there a different api for this in newer versions?

Comment: I don't quite understand it, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144906/error-running-heckle-currentcode-undefined-method-translate-for-ruby2ruby) recommends downgrading to Ruby2Ruby 1.2.2.  I also found [this monkey patch](http://gist.github.com/321038) which claims to add it back to later versions.  Haven't tried it though.

Comment: @Kludge You can use sourcify instead. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199603/how-do-you-stringize-serialize-ruby-code/6072624#6072624).

Answer (score 11):

**Use [sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify)**

This will work on Ruby 1.8 or 1.9.

```
def save_for_later(&block)
  block.to_source
end

x = 40
s = save_for_later {|y| x + y }
# => "proc { |y| (x + y) }"
g = eval(s)
# => #<Proc:0x00000100e88450@(eval):1>
g.call(2) 
# => 42
```

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199603/how-do-you-stringize-serialize-ruby-code/199803#199803) for capturing free variables.

**Update**:
Now you can also use the [serializable_proc](https://github.com/ngty/serializable_proc) gem, which uses sourcify, and captures local, instance, class, and global variables.

Comment: Is there an example anywhere of using sourcify with capturing free variables?

Comment: @rogerdpack, see my update. You may just want to use the serializable_proc gem if you care about free variables.

Comment: `sourcify`/ `SerializableProc`: no longer maintained (at least today)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970/how-do-i-marshall-a-lambda-proc-in-ruby).

Answer (score -9):

Ruby has the Marshal class that has a dump method that you can call.

Take a look here:

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/object_serialization.html

Comment: Marshal doesn't actually work on Procs, which what the question is asking about.