# main vs initialize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, initialization, program-entry-point

Okay, so I've looked through a couple of my ruby books and done some googling to no avail.

What is the difference between main and initialize in Ruby? I've seen code that uses

```
class Blahblah  
  def main  
    # some logic here  
  end  
  # more methods...
end
```

and then calls it using Blahblah.new.

Isn't new reserved only for
  initialize? if not, then what's the difference between the two?

Comment: initialize is the standard way because it is called automatically on new objects.  Maybe if you posted a complete example of where you saw main used instead, we could see what you're talking about?

Comment: I have never seen `main` used or recommended in Ruby as a method. Are you perhaps referring to the [top-level context object named "main"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby)?

Comment: I figured out the problem, which was with my understanding of what #new did. I was looking at a game engine that used a main function to load scenes in the main loop. I was missing $scene.main part, which explains everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Class#new` calls `alloc` on the class and then `initialize` on the created object. It does not call `main`.

The method name `main` has no special meaning in ruby's standard library. So unless you're inheriting from a class, which defines `new` or `initialize` in such a way, that `main` will be called, `main` will not be called automatically in any way.

Answer (score 0):

#### See class Class

---

Look up class `Class` in your Ruby documentation.

You will find a public instance method called `new`.

All classes are instances of `Class`, so they all have a class method `self.new`. As it happens, this method calls `allocate` to create the class and then, if an `initialize` instance method is defined for the new class, it calls it, and forwards its (i.e., `new`'s) arguments.

There isn't anything special about `main`.