# What is the difference between class_eval, class_exec, module_eval and module_exec?

Tags: ruby

I am reading the `Module` documentation but can't seem to understand their differences and which should be used where.

How is the `eval` different than `exec`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I'm going to answer a bit more than your question by including `instance_{eval|exec}` in your question.

All variations of `{instance|module|class}_{eval|exec}` change the *current context*, i.e. the value for `self`:

```
class Array
  p self                     # prints "Array"
  43.instance_eval{ p self } # prints "43"
end
```

Now for the differences. The `eval` versions accepts a string or a block, while the `exec` versions only accept a block but allow you to pass parameters to it:

```
def example(&block)
  42.instance_exec("Hello", &block)
end
example{|mess| p mess, self } # Prints "Hello" then "42"
```

The `eval` version does not allow to pass parameters. It provides `self` as the first parameter, although I can't think of a use for this.

Finally, `module_{eval|exec}` is the same as the corresponding `class_{eval|exec}`, but they are slightly different from `instance_{eval|exec}` as they change what is the current opened class (i.e. what will be affected by `def`) in different ways:

```
String.instance_eval{ def foo; end }
Integer.class_eval  { def bar; end }

String.method_defined?(:foo)            # => false
String.singleton_methods.include?(:foo) # => true
Integer.method_defined?(:bar)           # => true
```

So `obj.instance_{eval|exec}` opens the singleton class of `obj`, while `mod.{class|module}_{eval|exec}` opens `mod` itself.

Of course, `instance_{eval|exec}` are available on any Ruby object (including modules), while `{class|module}_*` are only available on `Module` (and thus `Classes`)

Comment: Note: when you module_eval lambda, it passes the module itself to lambda as the first parameter. module_exec doesn't.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I can't think of a single case where that would be of any use (use `self` instead), but I've edited my answer for completeness.

Comment: Thank you @Marc-AndréLafortune, but in the above example, where is the `mess` parameter coming from?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon the second reference to `&block`, where `"Hello"` is passed as the argument for `mess`

Comment: I've just discovered that on, for example, ::Oga::XML::Element I can call both instance_ and module_. Wanted to know the difference but answers here don't tell it. This article says "In effect, class_eval is an alias for module_eval." https://medium.com/rubycademy/ruby-class-eval-vs-module-eval-6c3cc24a070

Answer (score 5):

To answer your last question first, eval (in all its variations) is *completely* different from exec. `exec $command` will start a new process to run the command you specify and then exit when that finishes.

`class_eval` and `module_eval` have the power to redefine classes and modules -- even those that you yourself did not write. For example, you might use class eval to add a new method that did not exist.

```
Fixnum.class_eval { def number; self; end }
7.number # returns '7'
```

`class_eval` can be used to add instance methods, and `instance_eval` can be used to add class methods (yes, that part is very confusing). A class method would be something like `Thing.foo` -- you're literally calling the `foo` method on the `Thing` class. An instance method is like the example above, using `class_eval` I've added a `number` method to every instance of `Fixnum`.

Okay, so that's the `*_eval` class of methods. The exec methods are similar, but they allow you to look inside a class and execute a block of code as though it was defined as a method on that class. Perhaps you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo
  @@secret = 'secret key'
  @@protected = 'some secret value'
  def protected(key)
    if key == @@secret
       return @@protected
    end
  end
end
```

The class `Foo` is just a wrapper around some secret value, if you know the correct key. However, you could trick the class into giving you its secrets by executing a block inside the context of the class like so:

```
Foo.class_exec { @@secret = 'i'm a hacker' }
Foo.protected('i'm a hacker') #returns the value of @@protected because we overwrote @@secret
```

In general, with a lot of the tools in ruby, you could use any of these to solve a lot of problems. A lot of the time you probably won't even need to unless you want to monkey patch a class some library you use has defined (although that opens up a whole can of worms). Try playing around with them in irb and see which you find easier. I personally don't use the `*_exec` methods as much as the `*_eval` methods, but that's a personal preference of mine.

Comment: I think you're confusing `exec` and `instance_exec`

Comment: Not really? I mentioned `exec` explicitly at the beginning. `exec` doesn't really have much in common with the `eval` family of methods, so much as `{instance|module|class}_exec` do.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think the OP meant `*_eval` vs `*_exec`, not `eval` vs `exec`, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ambiguity I'm going to call a method that belongs to (owned by) a singleton class a singleton method. The rest are instance methods. Although one might say that a singleton method of an object is an instance method of its singleton class.

**tl;dr** Use [`class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval)/[`module_eval`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Module.html#method-i-module_eval) on a class/module to define instance methods, and [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.com/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) on a class/module to define class methods (or to be more precise, use `instance_eval` to define singleton methods). Additionally you can use `instance_eval` to access instance variables.

A terminology is a bit lacking in this case. `ruby` maintains a stack of class references (`cref` for short). When you open/reopen a class, the corresponding class reference is [pushed to the stack](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/insns.def#L725). And the current class refernece affects [where](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm.c#L2682) `def` defines methods (to which class/module they're added).

Now, `class_eval`/`module_eval` and `class_exec`/`module_exec` are [aliases](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L2171-L2174).

The `*_exec()` variants don't accept strings, and allow to pass arguments to the block. Since the `*_eval()` variants are mainly used I'll focus on them.

`class_eval`/`module_eval` changes `cref` and `self` to the receiver (`Thing` in `Thing.module_eval(...)`):

- [`rb_mod_module_eval()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1747) -> [`specific_eval()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1749)

  - [`yield_under()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1618) (for blocks)

    - [`vm_cref_push()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1578-L1579)
  - [`eval_under()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1634) (for strings)

    - [`vm_cref_push()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1608-L1610)

`instance_eval` changes `cref` to the [singleton class of the receiver](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1690), and `self` to the [receiver](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/vm_eval.c#L1691).

Let's see them in action:

```
class A
  p self          #=> A
  @a = 1
  def initialize
    @b = 2
  end
end
p A.instance_variables      #=> [:@a]
p A.new.instance_variables  #=> [:@b]
```

`@a` on a class level adds an instance variable to the class `A` as an object. I'm adding it here for completeness. But that's not how you add a class variable.

```
A.instance_eval do
  p self                #=> A
  p @a                  #=> 1
  def m() puts 'm' end
end
sclass = A.singleton_class
p sclass.instance_methods(false).include? :m  #=> true
A.m                                           #=> m

a = A.new
a.instance_eval do
  p self                  #=> #<A:0x00007fc497661be8 @b=2>
  p @b                    #=> 2
  def m2() puts 'm2' end
end
sclass = a.singleton_class
p sclass.instance_methods(false).include? :m2  #=> true
a.m2                                           #=> m2
```

So, inside `instance_eval` `def` adds a singleton method to the receiver (an instance method to the singleton class of the receiver). For a class/module that means a class/module method. For other objects, a method that is available for that particular object.

```
A.class_eval do
  p self                #=> A
  p @a                  #=> 1
  def m() puts 'm' end
end
p A.instance_methods(false).include? :m  #=> true
A.new.m                                  #=> m
```

And, inside `class_eval` `def` adds an instance method to the receiver itself (the class/module). `class_eval` is [only available](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) for classes/modules.

Also, when `class_eval` is passed a block, constant/class variable lookup is not affected:

```
module A
  C = 1
  @@c = 1
  class B
    C = 2
    @@c = 2
  end
  A::B.class_eval { p [C, @@c] }  #=> [1, 1]
  A::B.class_eval 'p [C, @@c]'    #=> [2, 2]
end
```

The naming is confusing. I might guess that `instance` in `instance_eval` suggests that receiver is treated as an instance (allows to change things for a particular instance), and `class` in `class_eval` as a class (allows to change things for a class of objects).