# Confused about NoMethodError in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In a simple Ruby example, I'm getting an error that does not occur in irb.

```
name = "Joe"
def say_hi
  "\"Hi there!\" said #{self}"
end
response = name.say_hi
puts response
```

This code should return, "Hi there!" said Joe.

It works perfectly fine in irb.  However, when I attempt to put the same code in a file and run the file, I get this error:

```
say_hi.rb:8:in `<main>': private method `say_hi' called for "Joe":String (NoMethodError)
```

Any suggestion about why this happens?

Comment: The answers more or less get it right, but what's your ultimate purpose? Adding a method to `String`? To that instance of a string? Of a new type that is like a string, but different, like a `Person`, or...?

Comment: My purpose was to add a method to `String`.  Still, thanks to everyone for the answers below.  Despite my purpose, I really wanted to know the distinction in behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there:

```
name = "Joe"
def name.say_hi
  "\"Hi there!\" said #{self}"
end

response = name.say_hi
puts response
#=> "Hi there!" said Joe
```

`def name.say_hi` will define a singleton method on your `name` and therefore you can call it as you expected: `name.say_hi`

Answer (score 1):

You defined method `say_hi` for `main` not for `name`. If you want define it for name you should do:

```
class << name
  def say_hi
    %["Hi there!" said #{self}]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you define methods in IRB, they become instance methods on **all** objects in the system. Including that string "Joe". But when you run the code normally, it doesn't happen. You have to add the method to String class yourself. Like this, for example:

```
class String
  def say_hi
    "\"Hi there!\" said #{self}"
  end
end

"Joe".say_hi # => "\"Hi there!\" said Joe"
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined a variable 'name` and a method. But there is no connection between them.

You could extend String:

```
name = "Joe"
class String
  def say_hi
    "\"Hi there!\" said #{self}"
  end
end
response = name.say_hi
puts response
```

Or you define the method for the object `name`itself (see [slivus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13574636/676874))

Or you may define your method in a module and extend your variable.

The advantage: You may also use the module for other object.

Example:

```
module Hi
  def say_hi
    "\"Hi there!\" said #{self}"
  end
end

name = "Joe"
name.extend(Hi)
puts name.say_hi

name2 = "Jane"
name2.extend(Hi)
puts name2.say_hi
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside irb (and inside the top level scope), self is set to main which is type Object.  This is described here: [What is "main" in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby).  So :say_hi is an instance method defined on Object, hence all receivers will respond to it including instances of String such as "Joe".

Try adding:

```
puts "Private methods: " + Object.private_methods.grep(/say/).inspect
puts "Public methods: " + Object.public_methods.grep(/say/).inspect
```

and you'll see that IRB adds public methods to Object whereas a script adds as a private method and therefore cannot be called with an explict receiver.