# How can I add a method to the global scope in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Sinatra defines a number of methods which appear to live in the current scope, i.e. not within a class declaration. These are defined in the Sinatra gem.

I'd like to be able to write a gem which will create a function which I can call from the global scope, e.g

```
add_blog(:my_blog)
```

This would then call the function my_blog in the global scope.

Obviously I could monkeypatch the Object class in the gem with the add_blog function, but this seems like overkill as it would extend every object.

Comment: Show us expected examples.

Comment: Hi Sawa, an example would be calling a function add_blog from the global scope, where add_blog is defined in a gem.

Comment: For an example of how Sinatra does it, see https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/cd503e6c590cd48c2c9bb7869522494bfc62cb14/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L28 and https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/cd503e6c590cd48c2c9bb7869522494bfc62cb14/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1873

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**TL;DR** `extend`-ing a module at the top level adds its methods to the top level without adding them to every object.

There are three ways to do this:

### Option 1: Write a top-level method in your gem

```
#my_gem.rb

def add_blog(blog_name)
    puts "Adding blog #{blog_name}..."
end
```

```
#some_app.rb

require 'my_gem' #Assume your gem is in $LOAD_PATH
add_blog 'Super simple blog!'
```

This will work, but it's not the neatest way of doing it: it's impossible to require your gem without adding the method to the top level. Some users may want to use your gem without this.

Ideally we'd have some way of making it available in a scoped way OR at the top level, according to the user's preference. To do that, we'll define your method(s) within a module:

```
#my_gem.rb
module MyGem

    #We will add methods in this module to the top-level scope
    module TopLevel
        def self.add_blog(blog_name)
            puts "Adding blog #{blog_name}..."
        end
    end

    #We could also add other, non-top-level methods or classes here
end
```

Now our code is nicely scoped. The question is how do we make it accessible from the top level, so we don't always need to call `MyGem::TopLevel.add_blog` ?

Let's look at what *the top level* in Ruby actually means. Ruby is a highly object oriented language. That means, amongst other things, that all methods are bound to an object. When you call an apparently global method like *puts* or *require*, you're actually calling a method on [a "default" object called `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917842/2806996).

Therefore if we want to add a method to the top-level scope we need to add it to `main`. There are a couple of ways we could do this.

### Option 2:  Adding methods to Object

`main` is an instance of the class `Object`. If we add the methods from our module  to `Object` (the [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the OP referred to), we'll be able to use them from main and therefore the top level. We can do that by using our module as a [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin):

```
#my_gem.rb

module MyGem
    module TopLevel
        def self.add_blog
            #...
        end
    end
end

class Object
    include MyGem::TopLevel
end
```

We can now call add_blog from the top level. However, this also isn't a perfect solution (as the OP points out), because we haven't just added our new methods to `main`, we've added them to **every** instance of `Object`! Unfortunately almost everything in Ruby is a descendant of `Object`, so we've just made it possible to call add_blog on anything! For example, `1.add_blog("what does it mean to add a blog to a number?!")` .

This is clearly undesirable, but conceptually pretty close to what we want. Let's refine it so we can add methods to main only.

### Option 3: Adding methods to main only

So if `include` adds the methods from a module into a class, could we call it directly on main? Remember if a method is called without an explicit receiver ("owning object"), it will be called on `main`.

```
#app.rb

require 'my_gem'
include MyGem::TopLevel

add_blog "it works!"
```

Looks promising, but still not perfect - it turns out that `include` adds methods to the receiver's class, not just the receiver, so we'd still be able to do strange things like `1.add_blog("still not a good thing!")` .

So, to fix that, we need a method that will add methods to the receiving object only, not its class. `extend` is that method.

This version will add our gem's methods to the top-level scope without messing with other objects:

```
#app.rb

require 'my_gem'
extend MyGem::TopLevel

add_blog "it works!"
1.add_blog "this will throw an exception!"
```

Excellent! The last stage is to set up our Gem so that a user can have our top-level methods added to main without having to call extend themselves. We should also provide a way for users to use our methods in a fully scoped way.

```
#my_gem/core.rb

module MyGem
    module TopLevel
        def self.add_blog...

    end
end


#my_gem.rb

require './my_gem/core.rb'
extend MyGem::TopLevel
```

That way users can have your methods automatically added to the top level:

```
require 'my_gem'
add_blog "Super simple!"
```

Or can choose to access the methods in a scoped way:

```
require 'my_gem/core'
MyGem::TopLevel.add_blog "More typing, but more structure"
```

Ruby acheives this through a bit of magic called [the eigenclass](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html). Each Ruby object, as well as being an instance of a class, has a special class of its own - its eigenclass. We're actually using `extend` to add the `MyGem::TopLevel` methods to main's eigenclass.

---

This is the solution I would use. It's also the pattern that [Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/) uses. Sinatra applies it in a slightly more complex way, but it's essentially the same:

When you call

```
require 'sinatra'
```

[sinatra.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra.rb) is effectively prepended to your script. That file calls

```
require sinatra/main
```

[sinatra/main.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb) calls

```
extend Sinatra::Delegator
```

`Sinatra::Delegator` is the equivalent of the `MyGem::TopLevel` module I described above - it causes main to know about Sinatra-specific methods.

Here's where Delgator differs slightly - instead of adding its methods to main directly, Delegator causes main to pass specific methods on to a designated target class - in this case, `Sinatra::Application`.

You can see this for yourself in the Sinatra code. A search through [sinatra/base.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb) shows that, when the `Delegator` module is extended or included, the calling scope (the "main" object in this case) will delegate the following methods to `Sinatra::Application`:

```
:get, :patch, :put, :post, :delete, :head, :options, :link, :unlink,
:template, :layout, :before, :after, :error, :not_found, :configure,
:set, :mime_type, :enable, :disable, :use, :development?, :test?,
:production?, :helpers, :settings, :register
```

Comment: So the methods are defined in a module (in this case called Delegator which simply delegates to Application). Then somewhere in the global context we extend the module which adds those methods onto main.

Comment: I think it's an excellent explanation, and welcome to Stack overflow!

Comment: Thanks! I've expanded the answer with some Ruby background. You clearly understood it from my initial explanation, but hopefully this will be useful to more people in the future.

Comment: This is a really great answer, and I'm not even looking for Sinatra info. Hope you get more upvotes for your efforts :-)

Comment: Wow, amazing answer! @joews if you haven't already you should make this into a blog post outside of STO as well.

Comment: Little side question: is there a way to reverse the effects of extending the Top Level object? Say we did `extend MyGem::TopLevel` but then we wanted the main Ojbect to forget about the methods that MyGem::TopLevel added, how can we do it?