# Ruby gem won't add method to global scope using extend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a Ruby Gem which, when `require`d, adds a function to the global scope.

I have followed the ideas here:
[How can I add a method to the global scope in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964016/how-can-i-add-a-method-to-the-global-scope-in-ruby), however, it just doesn't work! (on Ruby 2.4.3 anyway)

Here is my [actual source code](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-demand/blob/master/lib/demand.rb), but the below also summarises what I've done and what isn't working:

```
# example.rb
module Example
    def self.hello()
        puts "Hello"
    end
end
extend Example
```

Then

```
# app.rb
require 'example' # Having built as a gem
hello() #=> `<main>': undefined method `hello' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Drop the `self.`

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you clarify why, as this differs from the accepted answer in the other thread? This stumped me as removing `self.` causes every RSpec test to fail - but when I rebuilt the gem anyway, it works.

Comment: Another thing to drop is the brackets. Ruby omits these by convention to make the syntax cleaner: `def hello` and later calling it as just `hello` is the style to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio solved this for me, though I don't quite understand how!

It was considered good practice to encapsulate the methods in a module, so that users of the gem can use them directly (`hello`) or scoped (`Example::hello`) as they pleased.

By removing `self.` the method can be accessed directly only. By including `self.` it doesn't work at all. However, by doing:

```
module Example
    extend self
    def hello
        puts "Hello"
    end
end
extend Example
```

...it does work in both ways.

Comment: Should be `extend self`. And no, this code doesn't work :) `hello` won't be available at top level

Comment: That's how `extend` works. You give it a module and it adds module's instance methods to current object methods. This is why this code won't work. `Example` doesn't have any [non-built-in] instance methods. Again. solution is to omit `self.`

Comment: Thanks Sergio, whoops, typo fixed! Please can you vote back up. I am new to the site and only trying my best to participate but I am really getting kicked here. Thanks for your help.