# Ruby: Redefining const_missing method in Module's singleton class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Redefinition of `const_missing` method in the `Singleton class` of `Module` class doesn't seem to work. But it works if I redefine directly in the class `Module`. Any reason why?

```
class Module
  class << self
    def const_missing(constant)
      puts "This doesn't work!"
    end
  end
end

Hello
```

Where as the following works!

```
class Module
  def const_missing(constant)
    puts 'This works!'
  end
end

Hello
```

**Context**:

- Trying to use `super` in cases where the constants fall into a category thats not to be overridden. Say constants that do not match a pattern should still cause a `NameError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think defining `const_missing` on Module’s eigenclass is not working? It perfectly works:

```
▶ class Module
▷   class << self  
▷     def const_missing(constant)    
▷       puts "This doesn't work!"      
▷     end      
▷   end    
▷ end  
#⇒ :const_missing
▶ Module::F
#⇒ This doesn't work!
```

The question is what do you want to achieve? Whether you are interested in handling cases when your `Module`/`Class` is invoked to call it’s constant like:

```
module M ; end
puts M::MissingConst
```

You are expected to implement `const_missing` on `M`’s eigenclass. Which singleton’s superclass is apparently `Module` class itself, not Module’s eigenclass (`M.singleton_class.superclass => Module`.)

Whether you want to handle virtually *all* constants referenced by titlecased name without namespace, you might use:

```
class Object
  class << self
    def const_missing(name)
      puts 'bingo '
    end
  end
end

▶ F
#⇒ bingo
```

Comment: I am trying to intercept `const_missing` method on *any constant*, including thats not namespaced by `Module`. Try `F` without `Module::` in its front?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to google for 'ruby main context' (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/917842/2035262), since ruby will try to resolve `F` in all effective namespaces until it reaches `main` [pseudo]object. You probably want to define method missing on this main object’s eigenclass.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I am trying to override the Module thats at the deepest level so that any uninitialized constant can be dealt in a particular way.

Comment: Oh cool! `Object` is the one who handles `constants`? Was assuming I was already defining at the fundamental layer.

Comment: Just a detail: `M.singleton_class.superclass => Module`.

Comment: Didn't think `singleton_class` have any `superclass`! Thanks! I am yet to get a better grasp of the Ruby Object Model.