# Is there a default variable `hash`?

Tags: ruby

I typed `hash` in irb or in Rails console, and I can see it holds some random value. I do not know if it should be there or it's done by some gem.

Here:

```
hash # => -943824087729528496
```

Trying again:

```
hash # => 3150408717325671348
```

Is this normal? If so, what's the use? Or what does that value mean?

Comment: `defined?(hash)` reveals that it's a method and `method(:hash)` shows its origin

Comment: @Stefan I should have done that, but I guess I got too overwhelmed by my discovery to ask a question here :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, all top level method calls happen on the `main` object:

```
self
#=> main
```

`main` is an object with the class `Object`:

```
self.class
#=> Object
```

So at the top level, `hash` calls the [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-hash) method on the `main` object:

> ## hash → fixnum
>
> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have
>   the property that `a.eql?(b)` implies `a.hash == b.hash`.
>
> The hash value is used along with eql? by the Hash class to determine
>   if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that
>   exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.
>
> The hash value for an object may not be identical across invocations
>   or implementations of Ruby. If you need a stable identifier across
>   Ruby invocations and implementations you will need to generate one
>   with a custom method.

For more on the top-level in Ruby, see the blog post *[What is the Ruby Top-Level?](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)*.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By calling `hash` from the `pry`/`irb` one just calls [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) on [`main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby).

Comment: that explain it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`hash` is a method on object([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-hash))

Its part of the "top level" [more info](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)