# Defining in `main` versus `Object`

Tags: ruby, object

Is it equivalent to define a method in the main environment:

```
def foo; end
```

and to define it as `Object`'s instance method:

```
class Object
  def foo; end
end
```

or is there a way to distinguish them?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby, any methods defined on `main` are added as instance methods to `Object`. I have a feeling you were looking for something more definitive though.

Comment: @Linuxios The question is whether defining on `main` is different from defining on `Object`. I.e., are they two different things?

Comment: Yes they are different as to how I am not 100% sure just yet but very basically from irb `def foo; "in main"; end` will allow me to call `foo` anywhere in main because it is actually defined in the context of `main` but `Object.new.foo` will raise  `NoMethodError: private method 'foo' called for #<Object:XXXXXXX>`. So it appears when a method is defined in `main` it is privatized for Object.

Comment: @engineersmnky On my irb, they are not private. Maybe it depends on the version.

Comment: it seems that `irb` sets up a context and a workspace for you that holds these methods (although given the fact that you say yours are not privatized I am not sure this will work for you) but in irb i can call `self.context.workspace.private_methods` and the `:foo` i defined in the context of `main` is included in here. I am using `2.1.5`

Comment: @engineersmnky `main` is irrelevant to irb. Without irb, the main environment if `main`. Another way to refer to it is `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver`.

Comment: I cannot replicate what you are describing as *"they are not private"* (see my post below)?? Seems strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 2.2.1.

```
self
#=> main
self == Object
#=> false
Object === self
#=> true
```

So `main` is an instance of `Object`.

`main` is not equal `Object` - these are different things.

Defined methods in `main` and `Object`

```
def foo; end
self.class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:pry, :__binding__, :foo]

class Object
  def bar; end
end  
#=> :bar
self.class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:pry, :__binding__, :foo, :bar]
```

are both available for `main` and new instances of `Object`:

```
foo
#=> nil
bar
#=> nil
Object.new.foo
#=> nil
Object.new.bar
#=> nil
```

## EDIT

We can check the owner of the method defined in `main` (which occurs to be `Object`):

```
method(:foo).owner
#=> Object
```

It kind of implying you can't distinguish between methods defined in `main` and `Object`.

On Ruby 2.2.1 it becomes `Object`'s public instance method:

```
Object.public_method_defined?(:foo)
#=> true
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why I cannot replicate this? I am trying to understand why I show methods defined in the context of `main` as being `private_instance_methods` of `Object`.

Comment: @engineersmnky: yours is the correct behavior, IRb and some other REPLs are broken/incompatible in this regard. That's well-known and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't specify an object in whose singleton class the method should be defined, i.e. when you don't say

```
def bar.foo; end
```

but just

```
def foo; end
```

then the method gets defined in what is called the [*default definee*](http://yugui.jp/articles/846). Normally, the default definee is the lexically enclosing `module`, but at the top-level, it is `Object` *and* the methods become `private` by default. (The default definee can also be changed by various meta-programming methods.)

So, the two snippets you posted are *not* equivalent, because the first will define a `private` method, and the second one a `public` method:

```
def foo; end

method(:foo).owner
# => Object

Object.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:foo)
# => true
```

but

```
class Object; def foo; end end

method(:foo).owner
# => Object

Object.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:foo)
# => false
```

Note that in IRb and some other REPLs top-level methods may end up `public`. That's a well-known incompatibility leaking a private internal implementation detail of those REPLs and *not* an official part of Ruby's semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also read Sonoda's articles in the past, but may have missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

For me running a few tests I see methods being defined in the context of `main` as being set as `private_instance_methods` of `Object` not `public_methods`. This means unless you specifically define a private instance method on `Object` you should be able to distinguish them.

Strangely I cannot confirm the other posts showing that these are public methods of Object. If anyone has any insight on this I would love to understand. (Maybe it has something to do with the use of `pry`?)

I get the same in 1.9.3, 2.0.0, 2.1.5, and 2.2.3 so I am unsure why others get a different response.

**/scripts/test.rb**

```
puts "RUBY_VERSION: #{RUBY_VERSION}"
puts 'def foo; "in Main";end'
def foo; "in Main";end
puts "foo method response: #{foo}"
puts "Object.private_instance_methods:#{Object.private_instance_methods(false).inspect}"
puts "Trying to call Object.new.foo"
Object.new.foo
```

**(Raw Output):**

ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

```
RUBY_VERSION: 1.9.3
def foo; "in Main";end
foo method response: in Main
Object.private_instance_methods:[:foo]
Trying to call Object.new.foo
/scripts/test.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `foo' called for #<Object:0x640368> (NoMethodError)
```

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]

```
RUBY_VERSION: 2.0.0
def foo; "in Main";end
foo method response: in Main
Object.private_instance_methods:[:foo]
Trying to call Object.new.foo
/scripts/test.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `foo' called for #<Object:0x00000002d34b98> (NoMethodError)
```

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

```
RUBY_VERSION: 2.1.5
def foo; "in Main";end
foo method response: in Main
Object.private_instance_methods:[:foo]
Trying to call Object.new.foo
/scripts/test.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `foo' called for #<Object:0x2bec750> (NoMethodError)
```

ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]

```
RUBY_VERSION: 2.2.3
def foo; "in Main";end
foo method response: in Main
Object.private_instance_methods:[:foo]
Trying to call Object.new.foo
/scripts/test.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `foo' called for #<Object:0x593808> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: You are right that there is a difference between visibility, but that is not as crucial as what the owner is. If you define a private method within `Object`, then it will be the same.

Comment: @sawa agreed there is no direct specific way I have found to differentiate where the method was added. You could possibly use `method_added` to capture this but I have would have to test that.

Comment: "top-level" methods being `public` instead of `private` is one of the well-known incompatibilities of IRb with standard Ruby. There are also some others surrounding the usage of Refinements and the handling of local variables.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for  the confirmation. Honestly when I read this question my first thought was that I hope you specifically would chime in here since I have seen the depth of knowledge you have with the true inner workings of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, they seem to be equivalent, as Andrey Deineko's answer tells. However, my concern was that defining a method on `main` should result in defining an instance method on `main`'s singleton class, which is distinct from the class `Object`. For example, if I define a method on an ordinary object, I can see that it becomes an instance method of its singleton class:

```
s = ""
def s.bar; end
s.singleton_class.instance_methods(false) # => [:bar]
```

However, with `main`, it is different. Defining a method on `main` does not result in it becoming an instance method of its singleton class. The returned list does not include `:foo`:

```
def foo; end
singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
# => [:inspect, :to_s, :source, :kill, :exit, :conf, :context, :irb_quit, :quit, :irb_print_working_workspace, :irb_cwws, :irb_pwws, :cwws, :pwws, :irb_current_working_binding, :irb_print_working_binding, :irb_cwb, :irb_pwb, :irb_chws, :irb_cws, :chws, :cws, :irb_change_binding, :irb_cb, :cb, :workspaces, :irb_bindings, :bindings, :irb_pushws, :pushws, :irb_push_binding, :irb_pushb, :pushb, :irb_popws, :popws, :irb_pop_binding, :irb_popb, :popb, :jobs, :fg, :help]
```

So it looks like the method jumps the singleton class of `main` and is directly defined on `Object`. Hence, they cannot be distinguished.

Comment: I was also firstly thinking about singleton class of the `main`