# Calling a method without an explicit receiver in the main environment

Tags: ruby, program-entry-point

When I do:

```
def hello(*args)
  "Hello " + args.join(' ')
end

send( :hello, "gentle", "readers")  #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

is `send` called on something? I get:

```
method(:hello).owner #=> Object
```

Is it called on the `Object` class or its instance?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method call without explicit receiver:

```
send( :hello, "gentle", "readers")
```

assumes an implicit `self` as the receiver, which is the `main` object in this case.

Method definition in the main environment:

```
def hello(*args)
  "Hello " + args.join(' ')
end
```

assumes it is defined as an instance method on `Object`.

Since `main` is an instance of the `Object` class, the method definition and the call work together.

Comment: I found this post, which says: Ruby allows you to define simple functions at the top level scope. How does Ruby do this? Before your script starts to run, Ruby automatically creates a hidden object known as the top self object, an instance of the Object class. This object serves as the default receiver for top level methods. The string “main” is how Ruby represents the top self object as a string. http://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-top-self-object/

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
send( :hello, "gentle", "readers")  #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

is the same as:

```
self.send( :hello, "gentle", "readers")  #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

where `self` in this case is defined as `main` which is the built-in top-level object.

---

This line of code:

```
p method(:hello).owner #=> Object
```

returns Object because you've defined the method `:hello` at the top-level which means it gets put into the `class Object`.

Comment: Thank you. Your reference to main helped me find additional details.