# What is a "main" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a following lines in my ruby script. It gives the output as `main` when i run this script. But i cannot access that `main`. I don't know what is this?

Is an object or instance?

For example :

```
puts self #=>  main
```

If i access the "main" means it gives the error like "undefined local 
variable or method".

Previously i use this self to print its current object within a class. 
For example:

```
class Ex
  puts self #=> Ex
end
```

Here, i can use that self object to get the current class name. After
this i can able to access that `Ex` class. But in first example it
returns `main`. But i can't access that. So what is a reason 
behind this?

Comment: The same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby).

Comment: Everything is an object in Ruby and I do mean *everything*. This includes the "main" context of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

`Main` is the special object, with special properties.

More information:

You touched theme called `Introspection`. What information wikipedia gives about it:

> In computing, type introspection is the ability of a program to
>   examine the type or properties of an object at runtime.

So what you are doing is calling `introspection`.

So lets move further, what we can do with this?

```
puts self.class
```

This will give `Object`. So next important thing is:

> Everything in Ruby occurs in the context of some object.

So there is nice answer which [disclose this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby).

Comment: Ruby generally calls this "reflection" although like a lot of things in Computer Science it means roughly the same thing.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the comment, must i update my answer?

Comment: You're not wrong. I'm just talking about the local lingo used in the Ruby world.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword self in Ruby gives you access to the current object. In your cause, the Ex happens to be a class, not the instance of Ex. However, all the statements are being executed under the **main** object of ruby, as **main** happens to be the outer most object). For now the statement is inside the object **main**, meaning **main** is the inner most object. Therefore puts self is printing main as output.

for more information study:

https://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby/