# Ruby: @@ vs @ variables outside of classes?

Tags: ruby

I understand that a variable declared with @ outside of a class will become an instance variable of the object main.

Functionally, is this any different than declaring it as @@?

I was expecting @test declared in file2.rb  to throw an exception when accessed in file1.rb (through require), but it did not. Does this mean there is always only one main object and that @ and @@ are equivalent in this scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that a variable declared with @ outside of a class will become an instance variable of the object main.
>
> Functionally, is this any different than declaring it as @@?

Yes, it is. `@` is an instance variable, `@@` is a class variable. At the top-level, `@` is an instance variable of the main object, `@@` is a class variable of `Object`:

```
@@foo = :bar
# warning: class variable access from toplevel

Object.class_variables
# => [:@@foo]
```

> I was expecting `@test` declared in `file2.rb` to throw an exception when accessed in `file1.rb` (through `require`), but it did not.

This has actually nothing to do with your question: instance variables *never* `raise` an `Exception` when accessed, even when they don't exist. They simply evaluate to `nil` in that case.

> Does this mean there is always only one main object

Yes, there is one main object.

> and that `@` and `@@` are equivalent in this scope?

No, they are not. `@` at the top-level is an instance variable of `main`, `@@` at the top-level is a class variable of `Object`. And since class variables are inherited by all subclasses and all instances of the class and all its subclasses and (almost) all classes are subclasses of `Object` and (almost) all objects are (indirect) instances of `Object`, this means that top-level `@@` is an (almost) global variable.

So, the scopes of top-level `@` and `@@` are *very* different!

Answer (score 0):

No, they certainly are not equivalent:

```
@foo = 'bar'
instance_variables
# => [:@prompt, :@foo]

@@bar = 'baz'
# warning: class variable access from toplevel
instance_variables
# => [:@prompt, :@foo]
```

When you `require` a file, it assumes the context of the `require` line. I.e.:

```
# file1.rb
@foo = 'bar'

# file2.rb
puts instance_variables

# irb
require './file1'
require './file2'
# => [:@prompt, :@foo]
```

`main` is simply an instance of `Object`. You can read [more about `main` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917842/203130).

Comment: Thanks.. though this has me wondering, if it's not a scope gate, why can't I access plain variables declared in file2 in the script calling require?

Comment: @kehtyr You're right, I misspoke. Each file is defined within its own local scope, much like method scope boundaries. They are within the same `main` instance, though.