# Why does this instance variable fall out of scope?

Tags: ruby

Why does `@test` go out of scope in `Aclass`? When `a.print_test` is called, I get an undefined for `@test`.

```
class Aclass
  def print_test
    puts "@test from Aclass: " + @test
  end
end

a = Aclass.new
#a.print_test

#but still in scope here
puts "After print_test call: " + @test
```

On a side note, any one know how to get the run code button? I don't see it in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@var` is short hand to access an instance variable on the current instance of a class, or `self`.

```
@test = 'what'
puts self
puts self.instance_variable_get :@test

class Aclass
  def print_test
    puts self
    puts self.instance_variable_get :@test
  end
end

a = Aclass.new
a.print_test
```

So the scope has changed between the main program and the instance of the class.

Comment: The first `puts self` is `main`.  The second is the `class`. What is `main`?

Comment: That is a good question! Now, if only there were some website where one could [ask questions about programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/917811/2988)?