# What is the object in Ruby's "hello world"?

Tags: ruby, oop, object, methods, puts

If everything is an object in Ruby, to the point that even math operators are methods applied to objects, when I write:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

The method is *puts*, and the parameter is *"Hello world"*, but what is the object?

Comment: Strings are considered objects, so "Hello world" is a string object

Comment: "Hello world" is an instance of String. String is a subclass of Object. An instance of Object is an object. An instance of String is a specialised object.

Answer (score 11):

## puts

To find a method, you could call :

```
method(:puts)
#=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#puts>
```

So `puts` is a method defined in `Kernel`, available to every Object.

#### Kernel#puts

```
puts "Hello world"
```

is actually

```
self.puts( String.new("Hello world") )
```

Where `self` is the object [`main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917842/6419007).

So `puts "hello world"` is a :

- [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) method call
- on `main`
- with a String object as argument.

#### Notes

Note that if you execute

```
self.puts( String.new("Hello world") )
```

you'll get an error :

```
private method `puts' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Because every Kernel method is made available to every Object, but as a private method. You'd need :

```
self.send(:puts, String.new("Hello world") )
```

#### Test

Another way to check would be :

```
module Kernel
  def my_puts(*args)
    print "Calling Kernel#my_puts on #{self} with #{args}\n"
    print "Now delegating to Kernel#puts on #{self} with #{args} :\n"
    puts(*args)
  end
end

my_puts "Hello world"
```

It outputs :

```
Calling Kernel#my_puts on main with ["Hello world"]
Now delegating to Kernel#puts on main with ["Hello world"] :
Hello world
```

See? Everything is an object, even though it might not look like it.

## 2+3

In the same vein : `2+3` is actually `Integer(2).+( Integer(3) )`.

Answer (score 10):

> If everything is an object in Ruby,

That is slightly misleading wording. E.g. syntax is not an object, blocks aren't objects, a conditional expression is not an object.

A better phrasing would be: "every *value*  is an object".

> to the point that even math operators are methods applied to objects, when I write:
>
> ```
> puts "Hello world"
> ```
>
> The method is *puts*, and the parameter is *"Hello world"*, but what is the object?

There are two objects involved. I suspect what you really meant to ask is "what is the *receiver* object". (Actually, there are many more objects involved, but let's focus on the receiver and the argument for now.)

A message send always has a *receiver object*, i.e. the object that you send the message to. If the receiver object is not explicitly written out, it is implicitly assumed to be `self` (a pseudo-variable that always evaluates to the "current object"). Now, the question is: what (or "who") is `self` here?

This, by the way, is one of *the* most important questions you should ask yourself when writing Ruby code. Receiverless message sends are to `self`, instance variables are looked up in `self`. You should always be aware of which object `self` is at the point where you are writing your code.

In this particular case, when you write code at what Rubyists call the *top-level*, `self` is a pre-defined object Rubyists call `main`. It doesn't actually have a name, and there is no default reference to it, but `'main'` is what it returns when you `inspect` it or convert it to a string using `to_s`:

```
to_s
#=> 'main'

inspect
#=> 'main'
```

The second object you already correctly identified: it is the `String` object resulting from the evaluation of the string literal `"Hello World"`.

There are, however, more objects involved here. For example, `main` is an instance of `Object`, so `Object` must exist, too. `"Hello world"` is an instance of `String`, `String` must exist. `String` and `Object` are both classes, i.e. objects which are instances of the `Class` class, so `Class` must exist. `Object`'s superclass is `BasicObject`. `Class`'s superclass is `Module`. `Object` mixes in `Kernel` (which is an instance of the `Module` class). `Kernel#puts` returns `nil`, which is an instance of `NilClass`. `Kernel#puts` is just a helper method that delegates to `IO#puts` by calling `$stdout.puts`.

So, in addition to `main` and `"Hello world"`, *at least* the following objects are also involved: `nil`, `NilClass`, `String`, `Class`, `Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, `BasicObject`, `IO`, and the `IO` object assigned to the global variable `$stdout`, representing the standard output stream of your Ruby process.

That's 12 objects which are directly and intimately involved in the execution of your code snippet.

In reality, there are many more objects in even a simple Ruby program:

```
ruby --disable-gems --disable-did_you_mean -e 'p ObjectSpace.count_objects[:TOTAL]'
```

On my system, this prints a number around 9780 objects. Now, some of those are the `Hash` created by `ObjectSpace::count_objects` and the keys and values inside that `Hash` (such as the `Symbol` object `:TOTAL`), and of course the `String` created by trying to print out the result. But that's on the order of about ~35 objects, so there's still almost 10000 objects involved in the execution of, well, basically an empty program that does nothing.

Comment: Very interesting answer, as always. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant "everything" in the sense of "every value", and also "what is the receiver object". I took that "everything" wording from Bruce Tate's excellent book "Seven Languages in Seven Weeks". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `blocks aren't objects` Aren't they just disguised Procs?

Comment: @ericduminil no, block are not objects, they are just a piece of bytecode. Unless you materialize the block with `&` no object is created. You can use my `pry-objects` gem to validate that.

Comment: @akuhn : Thanks. Your gem looks good, I'll take a deeper look at it.

Answer (score 1):

***"Hello world"*** is the string object defined as a literal constant given as argument to the **puts** method

`puts "Hello world"` is in fact a simple way to do

```
puts myFoo
```

where myFoo must be a valid object... in your case `myFoo = "Hello world"`