# Ruby method scope?

Tags: ruby, methods, scope

In the following example:

**Main.rb**

```
def main
  obj = ExampleClass.new
  def multiply(a, b, c, d)
    return a * b * c * d
  end
  puts obj.multiply(1, 2, 3, 4) # this prints 24
end
main
```

**ExampleClass.rb**

```
class ExampleClass
  def initialize

  end
end
```

Why is the `multiply` method now part of the `obj` instance? (the `main` method is not part of the `ExampleClass` definition)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby nice concise (high level) explanation of how this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code written without additional `class .. end`, `module .. end` enclosures is executed directly, step by step, in context of special `main` object. This object can be referenced using:

```
2.2.2 :001 > self
# => main
```

Methods defined without additional `classes/modules` are defined as private methods of the `main` object, and, consequently, as private methods of almost any other object in Ruby:

```
2.2.2 :002 > def foo
2.2.2 :003?>   42
2.2.2 :004?> end
# => :foo 
2.2.2 :005 > foo
# => 42 
2.2.2 :006 > [].foo
# => NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for []:Array
2.2.2 :007 > [].send :foo
# => 42
```

Thus, in your code, `main` method (or it can any other method) is in the context of `main` object and so `multiply` method can be called from either `ExampleClass.new` or `Array.new` or from any other class.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Ruby)

**UPDATE**

Few notes from [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky)'s comment.

1. This is not a private method in main but rather a private method of BasicObject (in 2.0-2.2).
2. As of 2.3 (and in 1.9.3) this method is not even privatized.
3. It need not be an instance of the `class` e.g. `Class.new` as the class itself will also have this method defined e.g. `BasicObject.foo`

Comment: The main method was not wrapped in the ExampleClass.

Comment: What is `ExampleClass` then? Provide some code of `ExampleClass`.

Comment: `ExampleClass` is an empty class, I added it in.

Comment: @aoiee Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: A few notes 1) this is not a private method in `main` but rather a private method of `BasicObject` (in 2.0-2.2). 2) As of 2.3 (and in 1.9.3) this method is not even privatized. 3) It need not be an instance of the class e.g. `Class.new` as the class itself will also have this method defined e.g. `BasicObject.foo`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because both the variable `obj` and the context where the method `multiply` was defined have `Object` as parent/ancestor.

If you call `obj.class` you will get `ExampleClass < Object`. Supposing you are in the console, if you call `self.class`, you will get `Object < BasicObject`. So, in your code, you have defined a method `multiply` for `Object` class. That's why `multiply` is part of `obj` instance.

Comment: Sort of...methods defined in `main` (not the method defined by the OP but the `Object` `main`) are automagically added as instance methods of `BasicObject` since every object inherits, directly or indirectly, from `BasicObject` this method is available everywhere as long as the receiving object does not define an object specific version of the method (nor do any ancestors all the way up to `BasicObject`)

Comment: Methods defined at the top-level become `private` instance methods of `Object`, not `BasicObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Methods defined at script scope become private instance methods of `Object`. (Except in IRb, where they become *public* instance methods of `Object`.)

So, `main` is a private instance method of `Object`.

Method definitions inside methods do not create nested methods, i.e. `multiply` is not nested in `main`. Rather, each time you call `main`, you will create a new method called `multiply` as an instance method of `Object`. And for some reason that is not quite clear to me, it ends up as a *public* method.

So, what happens is the following:

1. you define `main` as a private instance method of `Object`
2. you call `main`, which will in turn define `multiply` as a public instance method of `Object`
3. you call `multiply`, which works because `obj` is an instance of `ExampleClass` which is a subclass of `Object`, which has your `multiply` method