# Method named `hash` in main module overrides some object's `hash` method

Tags: ruby

Given this script

```
def hash
  puts "why?"
end

x = {}
x[[1,2]] = 42
```

It outputs the following

```
why?
/tmp/a.rb:6:in `hash': no implicit conversion of nil into Integer (TypeError)
    from /tmp/a.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

It seems that the `hash` function defned in the script is overriding `Array#hash` in that case. Since the return value of my `hash` method is `nil` and not an `Integer`, it throws an exception. The following script seems to confirm this

```
puts [1,2,3].hash

def hash
  puts "why?"
end

puts [1,2,3].hash
```

The output is

```
-4165381473644269435
why?
/tmp/b.rb:6:in `hash': no implicit conversion of nil into Integer (TypeError)
    from /tmp/b.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried looking into the Ruby source code but could not figure out why this happens. Is this behavior documented?

Comment: I'm not getting this behaviour. `class Array; def hash; nil; end; end; puts [1,2,3].hash` prints an empty line and returns nil for me. `x[[1,2]] = 1` still raises the TypeError, but `x[nil] = 1` works fine. Wierd behavior indeed .. what ruby version are you on? I'm using 2.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not overriding `Array#hash`, you're shadowing `Kernel#hash` by creating `Object#hash`:

```
puts method(:hash)
def hash   
  puts "why?"
end
puts method(:hash)
```

That prints:

```
#<Method: Object(Kernel)#hash>
#<Method: Object#hash>
```

Fix it so we can see more:

```
def hash
  puts "why?"
  super
end

x = {}
x[[1,2]] = 42
```

Now the output is:

```
why?
why?
```

And no error. Try it with `x[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]] = 42` and you'll instead see `why?` printed *seven* times. Once for each array element, since the array's hash method uses the hashes of its elements. And `Integer#hash` doesn't exist, it inherits its `hash` method from `Object`/`Kernel`, so yours gets used.

Comment: On my system the second `method(:hash)` actually crashes the interpreter. Maybe Ruby devs should put a warning when top-level hash is defined...

Comment: Where/how did you try it? In IRB or so, or did you save it in a script file and run that?

Comment: Only in IRB does it crash. But redefining `Object#hash` still seems like a warning-worthy thing. I can't see that ever being a good idea.

Comment: Interesting. I did not think a method from the main script could shadow a `Kernel` method like that without explicitely specifying it.

Comment: @Becojo Didn't know that before this, either :-). I think the first paragraph of [Chuck's answer about the `main` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917842/1672429) explains it well.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a kind of hack in Ruby top level. Have you ever wondered how this works?

```
def foo
end
p self
foo

class Bar
  def test
    p self
    foo
  end
end

Bar.new.test # no error
```

How are two totally different objects (`main` and a `Bar`) able to call `foo` like it's a private method call? The reason is because... it is a private method call.

When you define a method at the top level of your Ruby script, it gets included (via `Object`) in every object. That's why you can call top-level methods like they are global functions.

But why does this break only `hash` and not other common methods? `def to_s;end` won't break `to_s`, for example. The reason is because `hash` is recursive: most* class implementations ultimately call down to `Object#hash` for their implementations. By redefining that base case, you break it globally. For other methods like `to_s` you won't see a global change because it's way up the inheritance chain and doesn't get invoked.

* the only objects this doesn't break are a few literals that probably have hard-coded hash values e.g. `[]` `{}` `""` `true` etc.

Comment: Hmm, `x[[[], {}, ""]] = 42` and `x[true] = 42` don't cause an error, but `x[[true]] = 42` does. I can't explain that yet...

Comment: I might have found the culprit. Starts at [line 666](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9cbb3bd1f2b05d59b6dd315ebdec295c2ced6c01/hash.c#L666) :-). Looks like `x[true]` uses `RHASH` to get the hash value of `true`. Which is defined [in `internal.h`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9cbb3bd1f2b05d59b6dd315ebdec295c2ced6c01/internal.h#L669), so I guess that really uses something low-level internal instead of our `hash` method. But `Array#hash` [uses `rb_hash`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L3964), which apparently does use our high-level `hash` method.