# Error running Heckle? `current_code': undefined method `translate' for Ruby2Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heckle

I'm trying to run Heckle, and I keep getting an error:

```
> spec spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb --heckle MyController

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!! exception= has a thick skin. There's nothing to heckle.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

(Runs through several mutations...)

/home/developer/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/heckle-1.4.3/lib/heckle.rb:603:in `current_code': undefined method `translate' for Ruby2Ruby:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: I forgot the gem versions:

```
heckle (1.4.3)
ruby2ruby (1.2.3)
rails (2.3.2, 2.2.2)
rspec (1.2.6)
rspec-rails(1.2.6, 1.1.12)
```

Comment: For those wondering if it this is deja vu, version 1.4.2 dealt with another change in ruby2ruby.

Comment: Apparently it moved:
http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27745&group_id=1513&atid=5921

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install ruby2ruby 1.2.2. There seems to be an API change in 1.2.3.

Just generated the docs for [1.2.2](http://rdoc.info/projects/seattlerb/ruby2ruby/blob/e29cce673a5b8986caa59ad885acde8c2bfd6d33) and [1.2.3](http://rdoc.info/projects/seattlerb/ruby2ruby/blob/2b9b3b1ee64b4c1d837423400a579cb39019e50b)

Looks like the class method 'translate' has been totally removed, although the docs don't reflect this